# what is good way to run a code after x hours after an API is called?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cron, settimeout, nestjs

I am building a nest web app with typescript.

I would like to execute some function x hrs after API is called but not sure how I can achieve this.

Because I want to run a function only once,
I think I can use `setTimeout`, but it that a good idea?
I was thinking to use cron, but as far as I understand, cron is to set a schedule and it will be repeated (correct me if I am wrong)

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: you can cancel cron job at any time, also read through the docs, it allows you to run on a specific date and time as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Cron Job.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#declarative-timeouts

If you read the documentation, it says that you could create a cronJob that executes after X milisseconds.

```
    @Timeout(5000)
handleTimeout() {
  this.logger.debug('Called once after 5 seconds');
}
```

So, you have to call this function when your API is called, then it would execute after X hours.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading. The OP is asking for executing a function x hours AFTER THE API IS CALLED. The NestJS @Timeout decorator doesn't work like this. It registers the timeout WHEN THE APP IS STARTED. So regardless of when the API is called, if you add a NestJS Timeout for, say 1 hour, it will be executed after 1 hour, regardless of API calls.